# Get value and convert to number?

Tags: javascript

I'm having an `input` like this.

```
<input id="test" value="150,000">
```

And I want get `value` from this `input` and perform calculations.

How can I convert `value="150,000"` into a number like this 150000?

I tried `numberFormat($("input[id='test']").val())` but it not OK.

Comment: A mistake in the tag caused you to think this is that duplicate. It's not. It's a question in JQuery, probably a duplicate of some other question....  See my remark to the answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove `,` and parse it to number

```js
function getValue(){
  let inputValue = document.getElementById('test').value
  let number =  +inputValue.replace(/,/g,'')
  
  console.log(number)
  console.log(typeof number)
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value="150,000">
<button onclick="getValue()"> Give numbers</button>
```

Comment: Obviously the question is in JQuery. The answer is to use parseInt: 
```parseInt($("#test").val());```

Comment: @pashute number with `,` cannot be parsed properly with parseInt, this is what the root cause of problem here, it doesn't make any difference if it is `jQuery` or `vanilla js` , try `console.log(parseInt("120,123"))` and see the result

Comment: Oops. You're right of course. Use js Number() function. ```Number($("test").Val());```